# store neon vector register to memory

Tags: rust, arm64, neon

This seems like a stupid question, but I can't for the life work out how to do it.

I have a buffer like;

```rust
let result_buff: &[u8]
```

and I have some code like

```
let anded_value: uint8x16_t = unsafe { vandq_u8(sa1, sa2) };
```

I just want to copy this result from the vector register to `result_buff[x..16]`, probably via an intrinsic?

basically it's 16 bytes long and I need to work out the syntax to copy it to a particular position in the `[u8]` / `Vec<u8>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the intrinsic [`vst1q_u8`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/core/arch/aarch64/fn.vst1q_u8.html):

```
vst1q_u8(result_buff.as_mut_ptr(), anded_value);
```

Comment: thanks! just pointing out my final solution was

```
// result is Vec<u8>
let write_location = unsafe { result.as_mut_ptr().add(x) };
// store the vector to memory
unsafe { vst1q_u8(write_location , anded_value) };
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be making it way more complicated than it actually is ;)

```rust
pub unsafe fn convert_to_array(d_in: uint8x16_t) -> [u8; 16]{
    transmute(d_in)
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/6M94bh4Pf